# Why are two different instances's isa pointer same?

Tags: objective-c, runtime

I think about the question for a long time. If somebody can help me, I will be very happy.
We know that every instance object is a struct which has a isa pointer.

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

So different instances should have different isa.But the fact is to the contrary.For example:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;    
@end
```

then

```
    Foo *foo1 = [[Foo alloc] init];
    foo1.name = @"foo1";

    Foo *foo2 = [[Foo alloc] init];
    foo2.name = @"foo2";

    NSLog(@"foo1->isa--%p", [foo1 class]);
    NSLog(@"foo2->isa--%p", [foo2 class]);
```

the result:

```
foo1->isa--0x10ed00df0
foo2->isa--0x10ed00df0
```

Two isa are same! Why are they same ? But the foo1 is diffrent from foo2! Where are foo1.name and foo2.name stored? Are the properties of foo1 and foo2 stored in a table which's key is "foo1" or "foo2" and the value are the property list？

Comment: Because they are of the same class. `foo1` "is a" `Foo`, and so is `foo2`. `0x10ed00df0 ` points to the `Foo` class.

Comment: I know that, so all properties of foo1 and foo2 are stored in the same isa?

Comment: @Park The `isa` pointer is a pointer at the beginning of an object structure which tells you what class the object is. The specific members of the class come _after_ the `isa` pointer in memory — in fact, `id` does not capture the full size of the structure; it just points to the beginning of an object (similar to how arrays decay to pointers in C: an array pointer in C just points to the beginning of an array in memory).

Comment: Two things with the same class have the same `isa` pointer, because the _class_ object is the same. What you are looking to compare is not `foo1->isa` and `foo2->isa`, but `foo1` and `foo2`, which are the pointers to the objects themselves. Those pointers are different.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Thank you very much! You help me ! The ivars are after isa pointer, because pointer is 8 bytes, so first ivar start from 8 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `isa` pointer (read: *is a*) points to the *type information* of that object, not to its *state* (aka set of the values of all ivars). Therefore for two objects (including class objects) of the same class, `isa` points to the same type information (the class). This type information is a generic description of the type (which methods are included, which ivars are existing), but not to the actual values (aka state).

The state is – to simplify something more complex – stored "behind" the isa:

```
instance i in memory
i+00 isa pointer           // points to the type, equal for all instances of a class
i+04 value of the 1st ivar // different for every instance
i+08 value of the 2nd ivar // "
…
```

So, when memory for an instance is acquired from the system, it is not simply the memory for the `objc_object` structure, but also for the ivars.

You can imagine something like this:

```
struct objc_object   struct myClass_instance
{                    {
  Class isa;           Class isa;
                       id my1stIVar;
                       id my2ndIVar;
                       …
}                    }
```

Please note, that for some years the real memory layout is different. However, this example is good enough for answering your Q.

Comment: Thank you very much! I get it! I search many articles and documents for the answer, but most people talk about class, metaclass, methodList, ivarList and so on. Only you answer is what I want and it is very clear! Real ivars are behind isa. And the powerful evidence is that the method "ivar_getOffset(ivar)"  returns 8 and the size of isa pointer is just 8! I am very happy!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote and/or check my answer.